# How do I perform a crc32 check on an Amazon S3 file

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A bit of background: We're trying to use mod_zip with our S3 bucket. We've found that mod_zip only reliably works if we provide the crc32s of the files.

Is there a way, without downloading the files, to get the crc32 of a file in S3? (I know once we have it, we could store it against the metadata. We could also perform the check before we put it in S3, but in future we want clients to be able to upload straight to a bucket).

Can't see anything obvious.....

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Could you get any solution for this problem? We are also facing the same issue and looking for CSC from S3 file without download.

Comment: Hi,
I'm afraid we didn't find a solution to the crc32 issue - however, updating to the latest nginx and mod_zip for that particular use case worked without the crc32 (and was fine with the filesize).

Answer (score 0):

Was working on a similar problem.  This works for me.

```
    crc_raw = zlib.crc32(file)
    # A CRC32 is 4 bytes long
    crc_bytes = crc_raw.to_bytes(4, 'big')
    crc = base64.b64encode(crc_bytes).decode('utf-8')

    upload = True

    try:
        current_crc = s3.head_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=filename,
            ChecksumMode='ENABLED',
        ).get('ChecksumCRC32', None)

        if current_crc == crc:
            upload = False

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        # if object does not exist; then upload else raise
        pass

    if upload:
        res = s3.put_object(
            Body=file,
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=filename,
            ChecksumAlgorithm='CRC32',
            ChecksumCRC32=crc
        )
```